# rpy2 3.2.0 on python 3.7 issues w/ importing robjects

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

python 3.7.3, rpy2 3.2.0, the following code:

`from rpy2 import robjects`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".virtualenvs/flask3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File ".virtualenvs/flask3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
  File ".virtualenvs/flask3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    _get_dataptr_fallback)
  File ".virtualenvs/flask3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py", line 50, in _get_symbol_or_fallback
    res = getattr(rlib, symbol)
RuntimeError: found a situation in which we try to build a type recursively.  This is known to occur e.g. in ``struct s { void(*callable)(struct s); }''.  Please report if you get this error and really need support for your case.
```

What's going on? This looks like standard procedure for rypy2, and indeed how we used it under python 2.

Same issue applies for any kind of rpy2 import: `import rpy2.robjects.tests` etc.

Comment: I'm also having this issue when trying to use rpy2 for testing on Travis. Looks like it's an issue with the cffi dependency of rpy2 which just got updated on conda: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/591/runtimeerror-found-a-situation-in-which-we

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and found the same issue @ejolly linked above. To get around it, I downgraded my `cffi` library from `1.13.0` to `1.12.3`.

```sh
pip install cffi==1.12.3
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: It sure does-- frustrating, but that seems to be the ticket (at least with me in python 3.7.3)

Answer (score 2):

**edit:**`cffi` 1.13.1 is released. Just update it and all should work.

---

The issue appeared with `cffi` 1.13.0, but appears limited to the ABI mode.

`rpy2` will try to use the API mode, but if it fails will silently fall back to the ABI mode. If your system can be configured to have a C compiler, the API mode should be installed. To force the use of the API mode, set the environment variable:

```
RPY2_CFFI_MODE=API
```

(see info box in the doc:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/overview.html#install-from-source)